# How To Retrieve Folder Tree With Smartsheets API Python

Tags: python, api, sdk, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to retrieve sheets with **Users.list_org_sheets(include_all=True)** from the Python SDK API.

With That I can see all the things I need :

```python
lstorg = ss.Users.list_org_sheets(include_all=True)
for entry in lstorg.data:
    print(entry.id)
    print(entry.name)
```

ss is the smartsheet.Smartsheet(token).
So with that i can see all the sheets in my domain, but when i try to download them with get_sheet_as_excel(id, path) I got that error:

```python
print(ss.Sheets.get_sheet('6157394402142084'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    print(ss.Sheets.get_sheet('6157394402142084')
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\sheets.py", line 525, in get_sheet
    response = self._base.request(prepped_request, expected, _op)
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\smartsheet.py", line 218, in request
    raise the_ex(native, str(native.result.code) + ': ' + native.result.message)
smartsheet.exceptions.ApiError: {"requestResponse": null, "result": {"code": 1006, "message": "Not Found", "name": "ApiError", "recommendation": "Do not retry without fixing the problem. ", "refId": null, "shouldRetry": false, "statusCode": 404}}
```

I guess that this error mean that he didn't find the file (Error 404) but I don't know why, just before i make the command to get a list of all sheets and then when i pick one of that (that i'm not owner with this token but the token is SysAdmin)

Thanks For the help

Answer (score 1):

The situation you're describing is due to how permissions work in Smartsheet. Using the SysAdmin token, you can successfully get the ***list*** of all Sheets owned by members of the account, but the SysAdmin token will not allow you to access the ***contents*** of those sheets, unless that SysAdmin user has been explicitly granted access to the sheets. You're getting the "not found" error when you try to retrieve the sheet because the SysAdmin user hasn't explicitly been granted access to that sheet in Smartsheet.

To actually retrieve a sheet that's listed in the "List Org Sheets" response, you'll need to add the **Assume-User** header to the "Get Sheet" API request to impersonate the sheet owner. You can find documentation about the **Assume-User** header here:  https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#http-headers.